# Multiple Scalar Expansion with subs command

Tags: matlab

When we use commands that given below, it gives the result by a `scalar` multiplication.

How do we do this multiplication operation by  `matrix` ?

```
syms x y
subs(x*y, {x, y}, {[0 1; -1 0], [1 -1; -2 1]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your symbolic variables x and y are scalars, you have to start with symbolic matrices:

```
x=sym('x',[2,2]);
y=sym('y',[2,2]);
t=x*y;
t=subs(t, x,[0 1; -1 0]);
t=subs(t, y,[1 -1; -2 1]);
```